# How to solve problem running MTCNN in JupiterLab

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conda, anaconda3

The function detect_faces() fails in JupiterLab:

```
image = Image.open(filename)
imageRGB = image.convert('RGB')
pixels = asarray(imageRGB)
detector = MTCNN()
results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
```

mtcnn version 0.1.0

The error:

> AbortedError:  Operation received an exception:Status: 2, message:
> could not create a descriptor for a softmax forward propagation
> primitive, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl/mkl_softmax_op.cc:306
> [[node model/softmax/Softmax (defined at
> /home/rikkatti/anaconda3/envs/poi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mtcnn/mtcnn.py:342)
> ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_828]
>
> Function call stack: predict_function

Comment: I'm facing the same error, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's probably due to the conflict of keras and tensorflow version.
I solved it by doing these steps:

1. Uninstall tensorflow from anaconda venv
2. pip install tensorflow==2.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way using cv2

```
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import os
import cv2
detector = MTCNN()
dest_dir=r'C:\Temp\people\storage\cropped' # specify where to save the images
filename=r'C:\Temp\people\storage\34.png' # specify the file name full path
try:
    img=cv2.imread(filename) # filename must be full path to the image
    shape=img.shape # will cause an exception if image was not read properly
    data=detector.detect_faces(img)                
    if data ==[]:
        print ('no faces were detected for file ', filename)
    else:
        for i, faces  in enumerate(data):
            box= faces['box']
            if box != []:
                box[0]= 0 if box[0]<0 else box[0]
                box[1]= 0 if box[1]<0 else box[1]            
                cropped_img=img[box[1]: box[1]+box[3],box[0]: box[0]+ box[2]]               
                fname=os.path.split(filename)[1]
                index=fname.rfind('.')
                fileid=fname[:index]
                fext=fname[index:]
                fname=fileid + '-' +str(i) + fext                
                save_path=os.path.join(dest_dir,fname )                
                cv2.imwrite(save_path, cropped_img)
except:
    print(' an error occurred')
```

This will detect all faces in the image and store them as cropped images in the dest_dir. Tested it with an image with multiple faces and it works fine

Comment: it gives the same output:(

Comment: do you have tensorflow and mtcnn installed?

Comment: see amended answer . I tested it and it works fine. You must have tensorflow and mtcnn installed

Comment: I have both installed

Comment: did you run it and check the print outs?

Comment: detector.detect_faces(img) gives the error which @rikkatti mentioned

Comment: Does anyone got solution, When I do this in Colab, its work fine but when I do it on my local machine which don't have any NVIDIA GPU, I get error.